# MSAL.Net not working when deployed to Azure App Serivce

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, adfs

I have an API which takes username and password and generate the `access_token` using MSAL.Net as shown in the code snippet below. It is working fine on my local machine, however I'm getting error when it is deployed to Azure App Service.

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> GenerateToken(string username, string password)
{
    var scopes = jwtConfig.Value.Scopes;
    var result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(
      scopes,
      username,
      ConvertToSecureString(password)
    ).ExecuteAsync();

    return new TokenResponse()
    {
       Access_token = result.AccessToken
    };
}

private SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in password)
         securePassword.AppendChar(c);

    securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
    return securePassword;
}
```

Error:

> There was an error parsing WS-Trust response from the endpoint. This may occur if there is an issue with your ADFS configuration. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa-troubleshooting for more details.
> Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

- Initially please  make sure the user is entering correct username and password , if not re-enter them to confirm. (user name in this format: username@domain)
- And when the app is deployed to the app service , please make sure the app is consented the tenant wide permissions from the portal directly by admin or when authentication in the process .

[image]

Please note that  Username/Password flow is not compatible with conditional access and multi-factor authentication.See [Username-Password-Authentication
| github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) So when app runs in an Azure AD tenant where the user/ admin requires multi-factor authentication, this flow may not be useful.
So try to disable MFA for conditional access if not needed.

[image]

You can check using WAM where AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword will let WAM handle the protocol and fetch tokens.

**References**:

1. [Acquire a token to call a web API using web account manager (desktop app) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenariodesktop-acquire-token-wam)
2. [2. How to acquire access tokens non-interactively for Azure Active Directory using username and password | (aaddevsup.xyz)](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/how-to-acquire-bearer-token-non-interactively-with-a-federated-user/)